# WCS : InvalidParameterValue and OperationNotSupported : Differences

Tags: mapserver, wcs, ows

In WCS 2.0 & 1.1, I'm looking for generate exceptionCode "OperationNotSupported" which is defines in OGC Documentations (WCS 1.1 / WCS 2.0 / OWS 1.1 / OWS 2.0). With MapServer 7, I've tested: `http://hostname:port/path?service=WCS&request=GetZZZ.`

XML response gives en error with exccode "InvalidParameterValue" 
I understand why there is this exceptionCode because it's an invalid parameter but when I can do the output with exceptionCode "OperationNotSupported"?

What do I do for that?

What is the difference between "OperationNotSupported" and "InvalidParameterValue"?

Comment: What if you add a version number parameter? Because all requests other the GetCapabilities require a version number.  So the InvalidParameterValue might be telling you that there is no version...

Comment: There is  the same exceptionCode with "...&version=1.1.1&identifier=xxxx" and "...&version=2.0.1&coverageid=xxxx"with DescribeCoverage request. In this case the layer "xxxx" exists

Comment: In that case Mapserver is probably reporting the wrong error code, and you should submit a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OWS Common, which is what WCS uses to define errors etc, tells us that:

```
InvalidParameterValue: Operation request contains an invalid parameter value
```

and

```
OperationNotSupported: Request is for an operation that is not supported by this server
```

and also

```
OptionNotSupported: Request is for an option that is not supported by this server
```

An `Operation` here is intended to mean `GetCapabilities`, `GetCoverage`, `DescribeCoverage` (from WCS core), but could include other operations provided by extensions, such as `ProcessCoverages` or `DescribeSpatialObjectType`...  even though these are specified using parameter values in a request.

An invalid parameter is when a parameter **value** (other than a value specified using a request parameter) is completely wrong, so considering the KVP syntax (HTTP GET) as below:

```
KVP syntax (name=value&)
```

If you were to specify *version*=**9.2.7**& then you should get the InvalidParameterValue error.

If you were to specify request=getcapabilites& then you should get OperationNotSupported, because in KVP syntax the **value** is case sensitive, and the specification tells us we must use the spelling `GetCapabilities`.

Similarly if you specify Request=GetXXX& then you should get OperationNotSupported

So in this example from a GeoServer service:

```
http://xxx.bgs.ac.uk/BGS_EMODNET/ows?service=WCS&request=GetXXX&version=2.0.1&
```

Gives us:

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/2.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="OperationNotSupported" locator="GetXXX">
    <ows:ExceptionText>No such operation WCS 2.0.1 GetXXX
[]</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Which is the expected response

I see that MapServer for a similar request

```
http://yyy.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_EMODnet_bathymetry/ows?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetXXX&CoverageId=BGS_EMODNET_AegeanLevantineSeas-MCol&
```

Gives us:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0.1" xml:lang="en-US" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/2.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="request">
    <ows:ExceptionText>msWCSDispatch(): WCS server error. Invalid REQUEST parameter "GetXXX"</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Which is not the expected response, so that is an error/misinterpretation of the specification and you may want to [file a bug report.](https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/issues)

Comment: Tkank you for your answer ! I will write a bug report to mapserver developpers for that mistake

Answer (score -1):

An invalid parameter is when a parameter is completely wrong, so when you ask for a request of `getZZZ` that is invalid as no WCS would ever give you a valid response for that.

An Operation Not Supported is returned when you make a valid request for something but this server chooses not to support that, I can't think of a WCS operation off the top of my head but for example a WMS may choose not to provide a GetFeatureInfo response by saying `OperationNotSupported`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74637/discussion-on-answer-by-ian-turton-wcs-invalidparametervalue-and-operationnots).